# In the main class to make an array of Contact

Tags: java

how to do an array of contact?
then how to put on a string and use "$" as a delimiter?

In the main class to make an array of Contact make typing of contacts. After typing put the data into a String using the "$" as delimiter

```
public class Contato {

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String numerophone;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address){
        this.address = address;
    }

    public void setTelefone(String numerophone) {
        this.numerophone = numerophone;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String numerophone() {
        return numerophone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name: " + this.name + " address : " + this.address + "  fone : " + this.numerophone;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You have to ask a question to get answers...

Comment: how to do an array of contact?

Comment: also post main() that you are using.

Comment: public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Contato> list = new ArrayList<Contato>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            Contato c = new Contato();

            c.setNome(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Name"));
            c.setEndereco(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Address"));
            c.setTelefone(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "phone"));
         list.add(c);
 System.out.print(c);
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main (String ... args) {
    ArrayList<Contanct> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

    Contact c1= new Contact();
    c1.setName("John");
    c1.setAddress("Arthur Street 10");
    c1.setTelephone("123");

    Contact c2= new Contact();
    c2.setName("Peter");
    c2.setAddress("Sam Street 2");
    c2.setTelephone("456");

    contacts.add(c1);
    contacts.add(c2);

    String result= "";
    //Put it to a String
    for (Contact c : contacts) {
        result+=c.toString() + "$";
    }
    result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of contacts:

```
private static final int MAX_CONTACTS = 100;
Contato[] contacts = new Contato[MAX_CONTACTS];
```

You can then iterate through the array to access each contact:

```
for (Contato c : contacts) {
    // Do something e.g.
    c.setName("Will");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how literally you want an "array of contacts", try:

```
Contact[] foo = {contact1, contact2, contact3...};
```

or

```
List<Contact> bar = new ArrayList<Contact>;
bar.add(contact1);
```